# MediaElement windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mediaelement

I am trying to play a video in my app. The video and the xaml file are present under the same folder.

My xaml code (which is a user control)

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">        
    <MediaElement x:Name="vid" MediaOpened="MediaElement_MediaOpened" 
                  Source="hey.mp4" AutoPlay="True" />
</Grid>
```

My xaml.cs file code

```
public Page1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void MediaElement_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    vid.Play();
}
```

The video is not playing. I tried the source to be "/hey.mp4" also, but it didn't play.
What is my mistake ?

Comment: did you add the user control to the page you want to play the video? And also. You don't need the vid.Play() if you set the AutoPlay="True".

Comment: @KasunKV yes, I did, when I tried to display a text box. It did display the text, but video is not playing. I used the media failed event, it gave me "System.Exception: 3100 An error has occurred." what does that mean ?

Comment: Can i see the code where you call this user control? I mean the XAML code.

Comment: Is your video set to resource, i think problem is with your video uri

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes, u were right. I tried Source="/userFolder/hey.mp4" where userFolder is the folder where both the files where present.

Comment: @KasunKV thanks for your time. The problem was in setting the source.

Comment: @Sajeetharan phone is getting locked when the video is playing. Is there a way to stop phone getting locked ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your URl of the video and to [`disable locking`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.useridledetectionmode(v=vs.105).aspx) of the phone, you could do this,

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```